# How to recreate the beautiful transition when you open an ingredient card in the apple example app "Fruta"

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am relatively new to swiftUI and iOS development in general and recently I downloaded Apple's example code "fruta" which uses appclips, widgets, etc.

I want to do something similar to the transition when you open an ingredient but no matter how much I dig into their code I can't find how they did it.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: i tried using a .spring() animation (it failed horribly), i tried .mathchedGeometryEffect(id: "card", namespace: namespace) and i tried a linear animation

Answer (score 0):

i found a way but i don't think it's the most optimal way.

```
struct IngredientCardTest: View {
@State var isCardShown = false
@Namespace var namespace

var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
        if isCardShown {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "card", in: namespace)
                .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 350, alignment: .center)
                .scaleEffect(isCardShown ? -1 : 1)
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        isCardShown.toggle()
                    }
                }
        } else {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "card", in: namespace)
                .frame(maxWidth: 190, maxHeight: 190, alignment: .center)
                .scaleEffect(isCardShown ? -1 : 1)
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        isCardShown.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

}